# Problems with Hidden nulls in text output

Tags: mysql, powershell, dhcp

I'm having problems with what appears to be hidden null characters in text data that I am trying to extract from a WINS server to create a list of machine names beginning with S and 6 numbers.

input data is something like: S123456        [20h]  DYNAMIC     ACTIVE      1234567     UNIQUE          6/7/2014 ...

```
$output_file='D:\blah blah\workstations.txt'
$regex='\b[S]\d{6}\b'

Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern "ACTIVE" |Select-Object Line | `
    Select-String -Pattern $regex -Allmatches|%{$_.Matches}|%{$_.Value -replace "`r|`n",""}|    get-unique > $output_file
```

When I try to load into a MySQL table I get S null 1 null 2 null ...   How can I strip the nulls out or avoid them?

Comment: What does your `INSERT` statement look like?

Comment: This might also be a problem with UTF-16 encoding (Windows default) being interpreted as UTF-8.

Comment: @tadman's suggestion sounds promising.  You can probably manually verify the encoding of $output_file using a decent text editor, and certainly try manually converting it to UTF8 and then loading in MySQL to see if that fixes things.  In your script, instead of using `> $output_file`, you could use `| Set-Content -Path $output_file -Encoding UTF8`.

Comment: I was wondering about something like that.  I'll give it a try, thanks.  Worked - awesome.

Comment: @JamesWing You should probably add that as an answer. I just had a hunch, but you had a solution.

Comment: This helps but I discovered that I needed ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer based on the comment sequence above.  You can set the encoding of the output text file.  Most built-in PowerShell commands that write text files accept an `-Encoding` parameter for this purpose.  So changing

```
> $output_file
```

to

```
| Set-Content -Path $output_file -Encoding UTF8
```

will set the file encoding as you specify.

Comment: This helps but I discovered that I needed ASCII encoding.